# GLSL, detecting the scalar between vertices in the fragment shader

Tags: glsl, interpolation

If I set a vertex to have a value A, and another vertex to have a value B, when passing that info to the fragment shader, GLSL will give me an interpolated value between A or B depending on the step between the vertices.

Is it possible to retrieve that scalar value?  When I receive my value between AB, I want to know the 0.0 - 1. 0 scalar from which that was derived.

Is this possible?

(Edit, to explain why) I'm trying to do an SSAO effect, but my geometry is very simple and I have large swaths of screen that will not be getting SSAO.  I figured if I could ONLY try to do the effect when I am close to the edge of a triangle, I will save lots of cpu.